# Revert a single file to previous version with darcs

Tags: haskell, version-control, darcs

One of the SVG files of my project became corrupt (I can't open it anymore with my editor).
I'd like to revert just this file to a previous version so that I can edit it.

I guess it must be possible to do that with Darcs. I should just apply the inverse of the patches to only one file. But how do I do that? Is there a command to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that to the last recorded version?  If so, darcs revert will help.  Otherwise, try `darcs show contents filename -p 'patch-name'`.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I made the file from scratch again, since this was not a lot of work. But this is good to know I can do `darcs show content -p 'patch-name'` to output a version of a file. Exactly the command I was looking for.